# Tag para "LuaJIT"

Tags: suporte, tags

Não seria interessante criar uma tag para "LuaJIT", a versão *Just In Time* da linguagem de programação [Lua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua).

Sugestão do *wiki* da tag:

> **Descrição**
>
> [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/luajit.html) é uma implementação de alta performance e Just-In-Time (JIT) da linguagem de programação [Lua](http://lua.org), escrito por Mike Pall. É muito utilizado como linguagem de extensão (*scripting*) em jogos, modeladores 3D, simulações numéricas, plataformas de negócios e em muitas outras aplicações específicas. Ela combina alta flexibilidade com alta performance com um uso de memória baixíssimo: menos de 125K para a máquina virtual (*virtual machine* ou VM) e mais 85K para o compilador JIT (em x86).
>
> LuaJIT possui um desenvolvimento contínuo desde 2005. Ela é comumente considerada uma das implementações mais rápidas de linguagens dinâmicas.
>
> **Compatibilidade**
>
> LuaJIT possui todos os recursos definidos na linguagem Lua 5.1. A máquina virtual (VM) é compatível com API e ABI para o padrão do interpretador Lua e pode ser utilizado em modo de substituição (*drop-in replacement*). Atualmente ela pode ser executada em todos os sistemas operacionais populares baseados em CPUs x86 ou x64 (Linux, Windows, OSX, etc), em sistemas baseados em ARM (Android, iOS) ou ainda em CPUs PPC/e500v2.

Comment: Mas, tem alguma pergunta relevante no site? Uma busca no SOPT não revela nada... No [so] tem só 443 resultados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags são criadas sub demanda. Quando surgir uma pergunta sobre Lua que seja **específica** sobre essa implementação (ou seja: não pode ser respondida sem o LuaJIT), então essa pergunta receberá a tag LuaJIT e ela será criada. Somente após isso uma wiki poderá ser anexada à tag.